# Segmentation fault ( Recorded nucleus image)

Tags: c, linux

This is my project from shcool and i have this error and cant figure it out! if you can help i really appreciate!
This code is supposed to create an image of a circle with random points inside creating a square! i think i need to solve this with malloc but i cant understand how!

```
#include <pthread.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <string.h>
//Função que calcula o pi

void*calc_pi(void*parameters)
{
    //inicialização das variaveis

    double npoints=100000000;
    double x,y;
    int i, circle_count=0;
    double D; //diametro do circulo
    double pi;

    for (i=0; i < npoints; i++)
    {
    x=(double)abs(rand())/RAND_MAX;
    y=(double)abs(rand())/RAND_MAX;
    D=sqrt(pow((x-0.5),2)+pow((y-0.5),2));


    //confirmar pontos dentro do circulo 

        if (D<=0.5)
        {


        pi=(double)4*circle_count/npoints;
        printf("pi=%f\n",pi);
        circle_count++;
        return NULL;
        }

    }

}


int main()

{
    //iniciar variaveis 
    enter code here
    double npoints=100000000;
    double x,y;
    int circle_count=0;
    int i = 0 ;
    double D;
    double pi;
    int numerothreads=5;
    int numpontoscirculo;
    double*npontos_circulo;
    double oi=npoints/numerothreads;

    //id da thread

    pthread_t thread_id;

    //criar uma thread que vai correr a funcao calc_pi
    pthread_create(&thread_id, NULL, &calc_pi,&oi);


    //fazer funçao join para receber os dados threads, criar funçao join para cada thread

    pthread_join(thread_id,(void*)&npontos_circulo);
    printf("O numero de pontos dentro do circulo:\n");
//fazer um ciclo para chamar as threads


    for(i=0;i<5;i++)
    {
    printf("%lf\n",*(npontos_circulo+i));
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Okay, so what is the problem with your code? Why it does not work? How can random points create a square?

Comment: Well, for one, your thread proc has only one conditional `return` option. Unless that path is taken you don't return *anything*, and effectively make a liar out of that `void*` you claim your function returns. From that, `(void*)&npontos_circulo` as the receiver of the phantom return result from your thread function will only get two possible outcomes (1) NULL, and (2) *undefined behavior*. *Neither* of those would be good candidates to dereference. Study more about how to pass data in/out of thread routine, and for all that is good in this world, *turn up your compiler warnings*.

Comment: Have you tried debugging this code?